# Multiple unique partial indexes in PostgreSQL sanity check

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I'm trying to figure out the best way to enforce a unique constraint across multiple nullable columns in PostgreSQL.

Considering the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  col_a character varying(255),
  col_b character varying(255),
  col_c date,
  col_d integer,
  CONSTRAINT test_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT test_table_col_a_col_b_col_c_key UNIQUE (col_a , col_b , col_c )
);
```

The combination of `col_a`, `col_b`, and `col_c` must be unique but they are also all nullable.

My current solution to enforce the unique constraint is to create 6 partial indexes (seudo code below):

```
unique(col_a, col_b) where col_c is null
unique(col_a, col_c) where col_b is null
unique(col_b, col_c) where col_a is null
unique(col_a) where col_b is null and col_c is null
unique(col_b) where col_a is null and col_c is null
unique(col_c) where col_a is null and col_b is null
```

Is this a 'sane' thing to do? Are there any significant performance issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is the only way to do it by declaration (using `create table`, `create unique index` etc.). Of course, each index must be updated. This could be a problem, if your table is growing beyond a certain limit.

This might not be applicable in all situations, but to avoid the need for so many indexes, I declare the columns as *not null*, and I put a *logical empty value* in it (for example: "*Empty*", "*None*" or "1900-01-01"). Of course, later on, either in ad-hoc queries or in an application, you might have to decode it back to a real *null*.